# How to insert the content of a file two lines after the line where a pattern is found?

Tags: sed

I have a file like as below and I want to search for the pattern "Unix" and insert the content of another file two lines after the line where the pattern is matched. I want to do it in `sed`.

```
$ cat text1
Unix 
Windows
Database
Wintel
Sql
Java
$
```

Output should be

```
Unix 
Windows
Database
CONTENT OF ANOTHER FILE
Wintel
Sql
Java
```

Comment: the first step to solving the problem would be to think clearly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks a bit funny, but this works with both GNU `sed` and BSD `sed` (on Mac OS X), and should work with most versions of `sed`:

```
sed -e '/Unix/{N;N;p;r content' -e 'd;}' data
```

Or:

```
sed -e '/Unix/{
        N
        N
        p
        r content
        d
        }' data
```

The `N` commands add extra lines to the pattern space (so the pattern space holds three lines containing `Unix`, `Windows` and `Database`); the `p` command prints the pattern space; the `r content` reads the file content and adds it to the output; the `d` deletes the pattern space; the `{}` group these operations so that they only occur when the input line matches `Unix`.

The `r content` must be at the end of a line of the script, or at the end of a `-e` argument, as shown.  Trying to add a semicolon after it does not work (after all, the file name might contain a semicolon).

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/Unix/!b;n;n;r another_file' text1
```

If the line doesn't contain `unix` bail out. Otherwise print it and get the next line, repeat and then read in the second file.

N.B. The second line following `unix` is printed first as this is now part of the current cycle, `another_file` is inserted into the pattern space following the end of the current cycle.